# Which manga is Puri Prisoner's dialogue inspired from?

Tags: one-punch-man, jojos-bizarre-adventure

Puri Puri, in One-punch man, always has a star in his technique names to go along with over-the-top expression. I find this style eerily similar to something I can't recall. My best guess is Jojo's BA, but I haven't read that manga, so idk for sure. Could you confirm? If yes, which character in Jojo has that style? If not, what manga it is then? Especially the "star" part, lol.